# Empty array prevents document to appear in query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents that have a few fields and in particular the have a field called *attrs* that is an array. I am using the aggregation pipeline.

In my query I am interested in the *attrs* (attributes) field if there are any elements in it. Otherwise I still want to get the result. In this case I am after the field *type* of the document.

The problem is that if a document does not contain any element in the *attrs* field it will be filtered away and I won't get its *_id.type* field, which is what I really want from this query.

```
{
    aggregate: "entities",
    pipeline: [
        {
            $match: {
                _id.servicePath: {
                    $in: [
                        /^/.*/,
                        null
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                "attrs.name": 1,
                "attrs.type": 1
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$attrs"
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id.type",
                attrs: {
                    $addToSet: "$attrs"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                _id: 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So the question is: how can I get a result containing all documents types regardless of their having *attrs*, but including the attributes in case they have them?

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Please can you edit your post with a sample example of your document?

Comment: If u unwind on an empty array then documents will be missed can u please add your document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in a `$project` stage to replace the empty `attr` array with one that contains a placeholder like `null` that can be used as a marker to indicate that this doc doesn't contain any `attr` elements.

So you'd insert an additional `$project` stage like this right before the `$unwind`:

```js
    {
        $project: {
            attrs: {$cond: {
               if: {$eq: ['$attrs', [] ]},
               then: [null],
               else: '$attrs'
           }}
        }
    },
```

The only caveat is that you'll end up with a `null` value in the final `attrs` array for those groups that contain at least one doc without any `attrs` elements, so you need to ignore those client-side.

**Example**

The example uses an altered `$match` stage because the one in your example isn't valid.

**Input Docs**

```js
[
  {_id: {type: 1, id: 2}, attrs: []},
  {_id: {type: 2, id: 1}, attrs: []},
  {_id: {type: 2, id: 2}, attrs: [{name: 'john', type: 22}, {name: 'bob', type: 44}]}
]
```

**Output**

```js
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "attrs" : [ 
                null
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "attrs" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "bob",
                    "type" : 44
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "john",
                    "type" : 22
                }, 
                null
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**Aggregate Command**

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            '_id.servicePath': {
                $in: [
                    null
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            "attrs.name": 1,
            "attrs.type": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            attrs: {$cond: {
               if: {$eq: ['$attrs', [] ]},
               then: [null],
               else: '$attrs'
           }}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$attrs"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.type",
            attrs: {
                $addToSet: "$attrs"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            _id: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm! Just as a side note: I am using MongoDB 2.4 so the $cond value must be an array instead of an object.

Answer (score -1):

use some if statements and loops.

first, your query should select **all** documents, first and foremost.

loop through all of them

then, if number of attributes is greater than 0, loop through the attributes. loop them into whatever array or output you find useful.

use if statements to sanitize your results if you like.

Comment: That's a possibility but, I wonder if would be possible to solve the problem just using the aggregation framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as fgalan said it would be awesome if I could solve this without having to pull everything to my side.

Answer (score -1):

You should use '$or' operator , and two seperate queries : one to select the documents with attr value equal to required value, and other query to match documents where attr is null, or attr key does not exist ( using `$exists` operator )