# Apply filter if value exists otherwise ignore - mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following field within my collection:

```
"intent" : [ 
  "Find a job",
  "Advertise a job"
],
```

What I'm trying to do is basically filter results on that field.

So if the end user passes in

```
[ 
  "Find a job",
]
```

I would then return all documents that have the intent `Find a job` this is my query so far:

```
var _intent = req.body.intent;

Reason.find({ intent: { $in: _intent }}, function (err, reason) {                 
  if (err) {
     res.send(err);
  }

   res.json(reason);

});
```

Now this works when I specify a value for `intent` as I'm using the `$in`-[Logical Query Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) however when I do not specify a value for `intent` it fails to return any documents, so what I'm asking is, is there a way I can say if `intent` has a value then filter on it, otherwise if it doesn't then do not apply the filter?

Comment: check this out it might help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510143/empty-array-prevents-document-to-appear-in-query

Comment: Seem's to be what I'm looking for, I'm new to mongodb and mongoose so excuse my stupidity here, but what does he mean when he says `So you'd insert an additional $project stage like this right before the $unwind` how would I tie that condition into my query mentioned in my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not set the query object dynamically?

```
var query = {};

if ( req.body.hasOwnProperty('intent') )
    query.intent = { "$in": req.body.intent };

Reason.find(query, function(err, reason) {

});
```

Or even

```
if ( req.body.intent.length > 0 )
```

Which ever case of logic suits. It's all just JavaScript after-all.

Comment: Seems to be working, and I personally prefer this approach, looks cleaner and easier to read on the eye.

Comment: @CodeRatchet Actually the link you were given is really about something different. Don't sweat it though, this is how we all do it. Queries are objects by design to allow you to manipulate them.

Comment: Thanks for clarification :)